# ActiveRecord merges current where conditions when applying a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, scopes

I have encountered some unexpected behavior in Active Record (3.2.13):

There is a simple scope on my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :verified, lambda { where('verified = 1') }
end
```

This can be used fine on its own:

```
  User.verified.to_sql
  #=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (verified = 1)"
```

When I concatenate `where`-clauses, they are `and`ed as expected:

```
  User.where(company_id: 1).where(company_id: 2).to_sql
  "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"company_id\" = 1 AND \"users\".\"company_id\" = 2"
```

**Problem:**

However, when I chain a scope, my first where-clause is nuked, the last one wins in a merge:

```
User.where(company_id: 1).where(company_id: 2).verified.to_sql
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"company_id\" = 2 AND (verified = 1)"
```

**How to apply a scope on a relation with existing conditions?**

(Those existing conditions have been established through cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` so I cannot just apply those `where` clauses *after* applying my scope.)

Comment: The "nuking" seems to happen in `merge`:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge ... which seems to be applied when using `scope`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gist sums up our findings on the issue. https://gist.github.com/kirel/5678865

It boils down to `ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named::ClassMethods#scope` using `ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#merge` which implements the unexpected *but intended* behavior.

Rails 4 will not use merge und thus behave as expected (see https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cd26b6ae7c1546ef8f38302661bbedf8cb487311). Meanwhile the workaround is to just avoid scope and use class methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
User.verified.where(company_id: 1).where(company_id: 2).to_sql
```

It seems that when you used `scope` after the `where` clause it simply create a new hash of the chained where clause and then AND it at the end.

hence

```
User.where(company_id: 1).where(company_id: 2).verified.to_sql
```

Gives you

```
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"company_id\" = 2 AND 
(verified = 1)"
```

BUT

```
User.where(company_id: 1).where(contact_id: 2).verified.to_sql
```

Gives you

```
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"company_id\" = 2 AND
\"users\".\"contact_id\" = 2 AND (verified = 1)"
```

Comment: It's not that easy in my situation. In my Controller: `load_and_authorize_resource through: :company`. cancan brings in two where clauses here: The first using params[:company] and the second using an ability rule (`can :read, User, company_id: @user.company_ids`). After that, I take the loaded and authorized `@users` variable in my controller and want to apply my scope.